# How to have elements proportional with screen's size?

Tags: html, css, xml, nativescript, styling

I'm havingsome trouble trying to use CSS in my app. When I emulate in my own device, everything looks good, but when I emulate in a bigger device, the elements stays with the same size, so there's an unexpected "margin".
How can I solve that? Is that simple?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more details, a minimal code sample reproducing the issue would be very helpful.

Comment: try adding '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">' this  should scale to full width of device without any extra margin. but please provide some code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having this problem if you're declaring set values in your CSS; instead, try using percentage-based values like `width: 50%`. As Soufiane stated though, it's hard to help without a code snippet.